Windows 11 Brings Up Minimized Applications When Switching To Another Computer With A KVM
I just upgraded to Windows 11 on my work computer (laptop, HP).
I have that computer attached to a KVM switch.
If I minimize all of my running applications, then press the KVM to go to another computer, Windows 11 will bring up/maximize all of my running applications.
How can I get Windows 11 to stop doing that?

Is the KVM sending key commands instructing Windows to do this? If you use a different KVM do you get different behavior?

I don't know.  It didn't happen with the same KVM and Windows 10.
I don't have another KVM

Perhaps look for a utility that logs keyboard commands and check to see what command(s) are being sent when you switch?
